# PhpStorm max function length

Tags: phpstorm, lines-of-code

I need to set maximum length (in LOC) of function or class. For example, when my function has more than 20 lines, PhpStorm should show me some warning.

I was looking for it in Settings->Editor->Inspections, but have not found anything like that for PHP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: PhpStorm has no such functionality.